# Opencv create new image using cv::Mat

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I'm new to OpenCV and I'm trying on some sample codes.

In one code,

```cpp
Mat gr(row1, col1, CV_8UC1, scalar(0));
int x = gr.at<uchar> (row, col);
```

And in another one,

```cpp
Mat grHistrogram(301, 260, CV_8UC1, Scalar(0,0,0));
line(grHistrogram, pt1, pt2, Scalar(255,255,255), 1, 8, 0);
```

Now my question is if I used `scalar(0)` instead of `scalar(0,0,0)` in second code, The code doesn't work. My question is

1. Why this happening since both create a Mat image structure.
2. What is the purpose of const `cv:Scalar &_s`.

I search the documentaion from OpenCV site (opencv.pdf, opencv2refman.pdf) and Oreilly's OpenCV book. But couldn't find an explained answer.

I think I'm using the `Mat(int _rows, int _cols, int _type, const cv:Scalar &_s)` struct.

Comment: what do you mean by "the code doesn't work"? Which line produce error?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

First, you need the following information to create the image:

1. Width: 301 pixels
2. Height: 260 pixels
3. Each pixel value (intensity) is 0 ~ 255: an 8-bit unsigned integer
4. Supports all RGB colors: 3 channels
5. Initial color: black = (B, G, R) = (0, 0, 0)

You can create the Image using `cv::Mat`:

```
Mat grHistogram(260, 301, CV_8UC3, Scalar(0, 0, 0));
```

The `8U` means the **8**-bit **U**signed integer, `C3` means **3 C**hannels for RGB color, and `Scalar(0, 0, 0)` is the initial value for each pixel. Similarly,

```
line(grHistrogram,pt1,pt2,Scalar(255,255,255),1,8,0);
```

is to draw a line on `grHistogram` from point `pt1` to point `pt2`. The color of line is white (255, 255, 255) with 1-pixel thickness, 8-connected line, and 0-shift.

Sometimes you don't need a RGB-color image, but a simple grayscale image. That is, use one channel instead of three. The type can be changed to `CV_8UC1` and you only need to specify the intensity for one channel, `Scalar(0)` for example.

Back to your problem,

> Why this happening since, both create a Mat image structure?

Because you need to specify the type of the `Mat`. Is it a color image `CV_8UC3` or a grayscale image `CV_8UC1`? They are different. Your program may not work as you think if you use `Scalar(255)` on a `CV_8UC3` image.

> What is the purpose of const cv:Scalar &_s ?

`cv::Scalar` is use to specify the intensity value for each pixel. For example, `Scalar(255, 0, 0)` is blue and `Scalar(0, 0, 0)` is black if type is `CV_8UC3`. Or `Scalar(0)` is black if it's a `CV_8UC1` grayscale image. Avoid mixing them together.

Answer (score 13):

You can create single channel image or multi channel image.

creating single channel image : `Mat img(500, 1000, CV_8UC1, Scalar(70));`

creating multi channel image : `Mat img1(500, 1000, CV_8UC3, Scalar(10, 100, 150));`

you can see more example and detail from following page.
https://progtpoint.blogspot.com/2017/01/tutorial-3-create-image.html